# A generic double linked list, assignment error in creating the list

Tags: c++, xcode, linked-list

I am writing a generic double linked list. I am getting a few error that I do not really understand:

[image]

[image]

I am not sure what the issue is here in the way I wrote my class but I am unable to get it to work. Perhaps it is the way I created the struct Node part but searching online it seems that this is a pretty standard approach.

Here is my code so far:

```
#ifndef DoubleLinkedLists_h
#define DoubleLinkedLists_h

template <class T>
class DoubleLinkedLists {
private:

    struct Node {
        T data;
        T* next;
        T* previous;
    };

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    // Constructors
    DoubleLinkedLists() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
    DoubleLinkedLists(DoubleLinkedLists const& value);
    ~DoubleLinkedLists();

    // Overload operators
    DoubleLinkedLists& operator=(DoubleLinkedLists const& rhs);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, DoubleLinkedLists<T>& data) {
        data.display(str);
        return str;
    }

    // Member functions
    void swap(DoubleLinkedLists& other) noexcept;
    void createNode(const T& theData);
    void createNode(T&& theData);
    void display(std::ostream& str) const;
    void display() const;
    void insertHead(const T& theData);
    void insertTail(const T& theData);
    void insertPosition(int pos, const T& theData);
    void deleteHead();
    void deleteTail();
    void deletePosition(int pos);
    bool search(const T& x);
};

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>::DoubleLinkedLists(DoubleLinkedLists const& value) : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {
    for(Node* loop = value->head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        createNode(loop->data);
    }
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>::~DoubleLinkedLists() {
    while(head != nullptr) {
        deleteHead();
    }
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>& DoubleLinkedLists<T>::operator=(DoubleLinkedLists const& rhs) {
    DoubleLinkedLists copy(rhs);
    swap(copy);
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::swap(DoubleLinkedLists<T>& other) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(head, other.head);
    swap(tail, other.tail);
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::createNode(const T& theData) {
    Node* newNode;
    Node* temp = new Node;
    newNode->data = theData;
    newNode->previous = nullptr;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    if(head == nullptr) {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
        temp = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        newNode = head;
        while(newNode != nullptr) {
            newNode = newNode->next;
        }
        newNode->next = temp;
        temp->previous = newNode;
    }
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::createNode(T&& theData) {
    Node* newNode;
    Node* temp = new Node;
    newNode->data = std::move(theData);
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    if(head == nullptr) {
        temp->previous = nullptr;
        head = temp;
    }
    else {
        newNode = head;
        while(newNode->next != nullptr) {
            newNode = newNode->next;
        }
        newNode->next = temp;
        temp->previous = newNode;
    }
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::display(std::ostream &str) const {
    for(Node* loop = head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        str << loop->data << "\t";
    }
    str << "\n";
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::display() const {
    for(Node* loop = head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        std::cout << loop->data << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}



#endif /* DoubleLinkedLists_h */
```

Here is the main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DoubleLinkedLists.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////// Double Linked List //////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        DoubleLinkedLists<int> obj;
        obj.createNode(2);
        obj.createNode(4);
        obj.createNode(6);
        obj.createNode(8);
        obj.createNode(10);
        std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        std::cout<<"---------------Displaying All nodes---------------";
        std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
        obj.display();


    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
#ifndef DoubleLinkedLists_h
#define DoubleLinkedLists_h

template <class T>
class DoubleLinkedLists {
private:

    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;
    };

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    // Constructors
    DoubleLinkedLists() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}                  // empty constructor
    DoubleLinkedLists(DoubleLinkedLists const& value);                     // copy constructor
    DoubleLinkedLists<T>(DoubleLinkedLists<T>&& move) noexcept;            // move constuctor
    DoubleLinkedLists<T>& operator=(DoubleLinkedLists&& move) noexcept;    // move assignment operator
    ~DoubleLinkedLists();                                                  // destructor

    // Overload operators
    DoubleLinkedLists& operator=(DoubleLinkedLists const& rhs);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, DoubleLinkedLists<T> const& data) {
        data.display(str);
        return str;
    }

    // Member functions
    void swap(DoubleLinkedLists& other) noexcept;
    void createNode(const T& theData);
    void createNode(T&& theData);
    void display(std::ostream& str) const;
    void display() const;
    void insertHead(const T& theData);
    void insertTail(const T& theData);
    void insertPosition(int pos, const T& theData);
    void deleteHead();
    void deleteTail();
    void deletePosition(int pos);
    bool search(const T& x);
};

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>::DoubleLinkedLists(DoubleLinkedLists const& value) : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {
    for(Node* loop = value->head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        createNode(loop->data);
    }
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>::DoubleLinkedLists(DoubleLinkedLists<T>&& move) noexcept : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {
    move.swap(*this);
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>& DoubleLinkedLists<T>::operator=(DoubleLinkedLists<T> &&move) noexcept {
    move.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>::~DoubleLinkedLists() {
    while(head != nullptr) {
        deleteHead();
    }
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>& DoubleLinkedLists<T>::operator=(DoubleLinkedLists const& rhs) {
    DoubleLinkedLists copy(rhs);
    swap(copy);
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::swap(DoubleLinkedLists<T>& other) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(head, other.head);
    swap(tail, other.tail);
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::createNode(const T& theData) {

}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::createNode(T&& theData) {
    Node* newNode;
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = std::move(theData);
    temp->next = nullptr;

    if(head == nullptr) {
        temp->previous = nullptr;
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else {
        newNode = head;
        newNode->previous = temp;
        newNode = newNode->next;

    }
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::display(std::ostream &str) const {
    for(Node* loop = head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        str << loop->data << "\t";
    }
    str << "\n";
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::display() const {
    for(Node* loop = head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        std::cout << loop->data << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}


template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::deleteHead() {
    Node* old = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete old;
}



#endif /* DoubleLinkedLists_h */
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the standard `std::list` container instead?  It is a standardized implementation of a double-linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors are caused by the `next` and `previous` members of `Node` being declared as `T*` instead of as `Node*`.

There are some other issues in your code, too.

- `operator<<` needs to take `data` as a `const` reference, because `display()` is declared as `const` (as it should be):

  ```
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &str, DoubleLinkedLists<T> const &data)
  ```
- `operator=` is not returning anything (it needs to return `*this`).

  Also, it is not handling the possibility of self-assignment.

  ```
  template <class T>
  DoubleLinkedLists<T>& DoubleLinkedLists<T>::operator=(DoubleLinkedLists const& rhs) {
      if (this != &rhs) { // <-- add this
          DoubleLinkedLists copy(rhs);
          swap(copy);
          // alternatively:
          // DoubleLinkedLists(rhs).swap(*this);
      }
      return *this; // <-- add this
  }
  ```
- No implementation of a move constructor or a move assignment operator.

  ```
  template <class T>
  DoubleLinkedLists<T>::DoubleLinkedLists(DoubleLinkedLists && value) : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {
      value.swap(*this);
  }

  template <class T>
  DoubleLinkedLists<T>& DoubleLinkedLists<T>::operator=(DoubleLinkedLists && rhs) {
      rhs.swap(*this);
  }
  ```
- Access errors in both versions of `createNode()`.

  You are accessing members of `newNode` when it is not pointing at a valid `Node` instance.

  On the first access, `newNode` is uninitialized (you are initializing `temp` instead).

  Your loop to find the last node when `head` is not `nullptr` is wrong, causing `newNode` to always end up being `nullptr` when you access its members a second time. The loop is unnecessary anyway, as you can (and should) simply append the new node to the right-side of `tail` instead.

  Also, the move version of `createNode()` is not assigning the newly created node to `tail` when `head` is initially `nullptr`.

  ```
  template <class T>
  void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::createNode(const T& theData) {
      Node* newNode = new Node;
      newNode->data = theData;
      newNode->previous = nullptr;
      newNode->next = nullptr;

      if (!head)
          head = newNode;

      if (tail) {
          newNode->previous = tail;
          tail->next = newNode;
      }
      tail = newNode;
  }

  template <class T>
  void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::createNode(T&& theData) {
      Node* newNode = new Node;
      newNode->data = std::move(theData);
      newNode->previous = nullptr;
      newNode->next = nullptr;

      if (!head)
          head = newNode;

      if (tail) {
          newNode->previous = tail;
          tail->next = newNode;
      }
      tail = newNode;
  }
  ```

  Alternatively, you can have one call the other so you do not have to duplicate the same logic twice:

  ```
  template <class T>
  void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::createNode(const T& theData) {
      T copy(theData);
      createNode(std::move(copy));
  }
  ```
- Not really a mistake, but the no-parameter version of `display()` can pass `std::cout` to the 1-parameter version of `display()` so you do not have to duplicate the same loop twice:

  ```
  template <class T>
  void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::display() const {
      display(std::cin);
  }
  ```

Comment: Could you expand on the access violations of createNode(). I removed the while loop but what do I need to do further to fix the other issues you mentioned.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx your `newNode` variable is not initialized before being accessed.

Comment: Could you see the edit I just made, I am having a problem with the else part of the createNode() function.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx I updated my answer to show code snippets you should be using

Answer (score 1):

You're using `T` for both the data and for next and previous pointers, when the pointers should be of `Node*` type just like the head and tail.